# Delete folder on multiple usb drives VBS

Tags: vbscript, usb-drive

I am looking to delete folder on multiple usb driver at the same time.

```
sDeleteFolder = "\Test"
Set oFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set dUSBKeys = ScanForUSBKeys()
For Each oUSBKey in dUSBKeys.Keys
    If Left(oUSBKey, 1) = "\" Then
       sKey = oUSBKey
    Else
        sKey = oUSBKey & "\"
    End If
    oFS.DeleteFolder sdeleteFolder, sKey
Next
Set dUSBKeys = Nothing
Set oFS = Nothing

 MsgBox "Done Del all the folder from USB Drivs", vbOKOnly+VBINformation+VBSystemModal, "DONE"
Function ScanForUSBKeys()
    Set oWMI = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\cimv2")
    Set dTemp = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
Set cDisks = oWMI.ExecQuery("Select InterfaceType,MediaType,PNPDeviceID,DeviceID,Size from Win32_DiskDrive")
For Each oDisk in cDisks
    If InStr(LCase(oDisk.InterfaceType),"usb") > 0 AND InStr(LCase(oDisk.MediaType),"removable") > 0 _
      AND InStr(LCase(oDisk.PNPDeviceID),"blackberry") = 0 AND InStr(LCase(oDisk.PNPDeviceID),"ipod") = 0 _
      AND NOT oDisk.PNPDeviceID = "" Then
        Set cDrivePartitions = oWMI.ExecQuery("ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskDrive.DeviceID='" & _
                              oDisk.DeviceID & "'} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_DiskDriveToDiskPartition" )
        For Each oDrivePartition in cDrivePartitions
            Set cDriveLetters = oWMI.ExecQuery("ASSOCIATORS OF {Win32_DiskPartition.DeviceID='" & _
                                oDrivePartition.DeviceID & "'} WHERE AssocClass = Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition")
            For Each oDriveLetter in cDriveLetters
                dTemp.Add oDriveLetter.DeviceID, 1
            Next
            Set cDriveLetters = Nothing
        Next
        Set cDrivePartitions = Nothing
    End If
Next
Set cDisks = Nothing
Set ScanForUSBKeys = dTemp
Set dTemp = Nothing
Set oWMI = Nothing
End Function
```

I keep getting a error :

```
 Type mismatch: 'oFs.DeleteFolder'  
 Line 12   Char 5
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Study the docs for [.DeleteFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ca0at0xh(v=vs.84).aspx)
2. Make sure you pass the full path (not just "\test") and the appropriate boolean (not a string like oUSBKey) when you call the Sub
3. Use [.BuildPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z0z2z1zt(v=vs.84).aspx) to build that full path
4. Use the good features of VBScript. E.g.: `Option Explicit`, declare sPath as Const
5. Don't use `Set x = Nothing` in vain

Comment: Thank you for your info. Wish can set the patch. but trying to delete the folder from 4 or more usb driver at the same time. I will look into your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
sDeleteFolder = "\Test"
For Each oUSBKey in dUSBKeys.Keys
    sKey = oUSBKey & sDeleteFolder
    oFS.DeleteFolder sKey
Next
```

Comment: Will need to try it out. I am looking to delete only one folder. The Test Dir only. .

Comment: thats different problem... you don't need wild card to delete a folder..

Comment: I try it update code. Thank you it works great thank's